# Как приложение на Vue внедрить в разные места одной страницы?

Tags: vue.js, шаблоны

Имеется такой html код, который генерируется на сервере.

```
<div id="app1"></div>
<p>контент, который генерируется на сервере</p>
<div id="app2"></div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

В app1 и app2 должно быть vue приложение (точнее что-то типа отдельных модулей (например, форма поиска и каталог).
Как такое реализовать?
Единственный способ, который пришёл на ум, это делать разные компиляции vue для разных блоков и подключать два файла js. 
В итоге получится так

```
 <div id="app1"></div>
<p>контент, который генерируется на сервере</p>
<div id="app2"></div>
<script src="app1.js"></script>
<script src="app2.js"></script>
```

но это решение мне не нравится совсем.

Привожу пример app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

import App from './components/App.vue';
import Block1 from './components/Block1.vue';
import Block2 from './components/Block2 .vue';

Vue.component('Block2',Block2 );
Vue.component('Block1',Block1);

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
{
    path : '/test',
    component : Block1
},

];

const router = new VueRouter ({
mode: 'history',
routes
});

 import axios from 'axios';
 axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer 1111111111111';

new Vue({
router,
el: '#app',
render: h => h(App)
})
```

И пример App.vue

```
<script src="../app.js"></script>
<template>
    <div>


        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {

  data () {
    return {
    }  
  },

  mounted: function () {
    //console.log('App component mounted');
  },

  methods: {

  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `<div>Первый инстанс Vue</div>`,
});

const app2 = new Vue({
  el: '#app2',
  template: `<div>Второй инстанс Vue</div>`,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>

<div id="app">
</div>
<P>контент, который генерируется на сервере</P>
<div id="app2">
</div>
```

П.С.:
файл App.vue должен выглядеть так

```
    <template>
        <div>
           <Block1 />
            <router-view></router-view>
           <Block2 />
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import Block1 from './components/Block1.vue';
    import Block2 from './components/Block2 .vue';

    export default {
      components: {Block1, Block2}

      data () {
        return {
        }  
      },

      mounted: function () {
        //console.log('App component mounted');
      },

      methods: {

      }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Ошибка при компиляции.

Comment: к сожалению, я не телепат. Ваш итоговый код не вижу. Как видите, здесь все работает. Локакльно у меня тоже работает

Comment: Дополнил свой вопрос  недостающим кодом. Хочется, чтобы на одну страницу я мог подключать разные блоки Vue

Answer (score 0):

Вместо создания экземпляров приложения обычным образом - объяви их *как объекты*, а также объяви функцию-фабрику, которая будет создавать экземпляр и монтировать его на DOM-элемент:

```js
// в общем js-бандле
const exampleVueObject = {
  data: { hello: '' },
  mounted: function () {
    this.hello = 'Привет, я экземпляр Vue на элементе #' + this.$el.id;
  }
};
function createVueInst(el, vueObj) {      // та самая фабрика инстансов Vue
  const tmp = _.cloneDeep(vueObj);        // клонирование тут средствами lodash
  tmp.el = el;
  return new Vue(tmp);
}

// в скрипте на странице
const vm1 = createVueInst('#app1', exampleVueObject);
const vm2 = createVueInst('#app2', exampleVueObject);
```

```css
div { margin: 0 0 1rem 0; padding: 0.5rem; font-family: sans-serif; text-align: center; outline: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

```html
<div id="app1">{{ hello }}</div>
<div id="app2">{{ hello }}</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Конечно же, объекты Vue могут иметь совершенно различный набор компонентов и различную логику (в примере - оба одинаковы, т.к. инстанцируются из одинаковых объектов).

Роутеры - должны быть разными: свой для каждого экземпляра.
Что касается Vuex, то он по-моему может быть единым для нескольких корневых экземпляров. Если вдруг нет, то можно использовать технику [event bus](https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860).

Вызывать фабрику лучше из "голого" JS, и желательно прямо в документе (кодом в теге `<script>`), но это не принципиально.